# How to advertise a custom uuid using BLE Qt framework?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been experimenting with Qt's example project, Heart Rate Server. I got it to work on Linux and my iPhone app successfully recognizes Heart Rate peripheral, connects to it and get notified about heart rate value changes.

Now I would like to modify Heart Rate example project to advertise a custom service with a custom characteristic. I generated two 128-bit UUIDs for the custom service and characteristic, but when I change the code to advertise them, my iPhone app always recognizes the HeartRate service with the HeartRateMeasurement characteristic.

I even tried advertising a peripheral with no services (code below) and my iPhone app still recognizes that the peripheral is advertising the HeartRate service, even though it isn't.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLowEnergyAdvertisingData advertisingData;
    advertisingData.setDiscoverability(QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::DiscoverabilityGeneral);
    advertisingData.setIncludePowerLevel(true);
    advertisingData.setLocalName("000000-000000-00");

    QLowEnergyController *leController = QLowEnergyController::createPeripheral();
    leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData,
                                   advertisingData);

    return a.exec();
}
```

What can I do to advertise a custom service and characteristic? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, iPhone was caching bluetooth data for the peripheral which is why it was always discovering the same service and characteristic. Turning bluetooth off and on again on iPhone fixed the problem. Hopefully this might help someone who runs into the same issue.